# Substitute string between two patterns in a file using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

This is my file

```
Dummy lines
#### topo ########
Image version is v1
path is url/v1
Use the image v1 for deploying
##################
some more dummy lines
```

I need to replace v1 with v2 only between #### topo ######## and ################## and not in dummy lines and some more dummy lines.
Expected output -

```
Dummy lines
#### topo ########
Image version is v2
path is url/v2
Use the image v2 for deploying
##################
some more dummy lines
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '/^###.*/{process=!process}process{gsub("v1","v2")}1' yourfile
```

This

1. looks for lines that match the start/end of your block `/^###.*/`
2. and toggles a variable `process` between true and false. `{process=!process}`
3. if `process` is true, then it replaces "v1" with "v2". `gsub("v1","v2")`
4. and then prints (using shorthand `1`/true) to trigger the default print behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{doStuff = "NOPE"}

{
if ($0 == "#### topo ########") {doStuff = "YUP"}
if ($0 == "##################") {doStuff = "NOPE"}

if (doStuff == "YUP") { gsub("v1","v2") }
print
}' yourfile
```

the easy, but unelegant answer. You can change == to ~ for contains something instead of must equal to that string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` range pattern, we can exclude the actions in `{}` to records (lines by default) matched in range pattern.

```
awk '/#### topo ########/,/##################/{gsub("v1",v2")}' input.txt
```